# Insert Tab bar at second view of application and tab bar contains more than 5 tabs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

**Other Solution for adding 6 tabs is also acceptable**

As for More Than 5 tabs i have used CiExpandableTabBarController
Problem is:
If i add CiExpandableTabBarController Like this:
self.window.rootViewController=CiExpandableTabBarController; 
then there is no problem..

but i need to add this for second view and views after that..
my first view is login so after first, view tab bar should be visible

now i am getting output like this:

selected tebbar item image is not displayed

[image]

[image]

But i want Output like this:

[image]

i have added tab bar like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

[self makeTabBar];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
//==============


self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.



if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
    {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_3" bundle:nil];
    }

} else {
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
}

UINavigationController *nvc=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.window.rootViewController=nvc;
[nvc setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
//    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


return YES;
}

-(void)makeTabBar
{
//    self.tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];
//    self.tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = nil;


ProductSearchViewController *homeObj;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
    {
        homeObj=[[ProductSearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProductSearchViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        homeObj=[[ProductSearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProductSearchViewController_3" bundle:nil];
    }
}
else
{
    homeObj=[[ProductSearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProductSearchViewController~ipad" bundle:nil];
}
UINavigationController *tab1Controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeObj];
tab1Controller.title=@"Product Seach";
tab1Controller.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"productsearch.png"];

WhereToBuyViewController *chatListObj;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
    {
            chatListObj=[[WhereToBuyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WhereToBuyViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        chatListObj=[[WhereToBuyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WhereToBuyViewController_3" bundle:nil];
    }
}
else
{
    chatListObj=[[WhereToBuyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WhereToBuyViewController~ipad" bundle:nil];
}
UINavigationController *tab2Controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:chatListObj];
tab2Controller.title=@"Where To Buy";
tab2Controller.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"wheretobuy.png"];

//===========tab3
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
    {
        chatListObj=[[WhereToBuyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WhereToBuyViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        chatListObj=[[WhereToBuyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WhereToBuyViewController_3" bundle:nil];
    }
}
else
{
    chatListObj=[[WhereToBuyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WhereToBuyViewController~ipad" bundle:nil];
}
UINavigationController *tab3Controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:chatListObj];
tab3Controller.title=@"Where To Buy";
tab3Controller.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"wheretobuy.png"];
//====================tab4
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
    {
        chatListObj=[[WhereToBuyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WhereToBuyViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        chatListObj=[[WhereToBuyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WhereToBuyViewController_3" bundle:nil];
    }
}
else
{
    chatListObj=[[WhereToBuyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WhereToBuyViewController~ipad" bundle:nil];
}
UINavigationController *tab4Controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:chatListObj];
tab4Controller.title=@"Where To Buy";
tab4Controller.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"wheretobuy.png"];
//==============tabtab5

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
    {
        chatListObj=[[WhereToBuyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WhereToBuyViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        chatListObj=[[WhereToBuyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WhereToBuyViewController_3" bundle:nil];
    }
}
else
{
    chatListObj=[[WhereToBuyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WhereToBuyViewController~ipad" bundle:nil];
}
UINavigationController *tab5Controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:chatListObj];
tab5Controller.title=@"Where To Buy";
tab5Controller.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"wheretobuy.png"];
//=========================tab 6

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
    {
        chatListObj=[[WhereToBuyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WhereToBuyViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        chatListObj=[[WhereToBuyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WhereToBuyViewController_3" bundle:nil];
    }
}
else
{
    chatListObj=[[WhereToBuyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WhereToBuyViewController~ipad" bundle:nil];
}
UINavigationController *tab6Controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:chatListObj];
tab6Controller.title=@"Where To Buy";
tab2Controller.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"wheretobuy.png"];
//=======================
CiExpandableTabBarController *tabbar=[[CiExpandableTabBarController alloc] initWithViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:tab1Controller,tab2Controller,tab3Controller,tab4Controller,tab5Controller,tab6Controller, nil] andSelectedIndex:0];
[self.window addSubview:tabbar.view];
}
```

Comment: So what exactly was your question?

Comment: There is a selectedBackgroundImage, just set it...

Comment: no such option of selectedBackgroundImage

Answer (score 0):

For the selected image and unselected image of a `UITabBarItem`, there are two properties of it namely `finishedSelectedImage` and `finishedUnselectedImage`. But you simply cannot set those properties because they don't have any setter method defined for them, just the getter.

Instead you can do something like this. Suppose 'tab_1_unselImg' is your unselected tab image and 'tab_1_selImg' is for selected tab for the first tab of your tab bar controller.

```
[[[[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] tabBarItem] 
setFinishedSelectedImage:tab_1_selImg withFinishedUnselectedImage:tab_1_unselImg];
```